# JUnit maven tests are being found but not executed

Tags: maven, kotlin, junit

I have added the following test file to my maven project in `src/test/kotlin/com/jemtucker/domain/HelloWorldTest.kt`

```
package com.jemtucker.domain

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions

class HelloWorldTest {

    @Test
    fun `Adding 3 and 3 should be equal to 6`() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(6, 3 + 3)
    }
}
```

Running `mvn test` compiles the tests successfully and seems to discover them but none of the test functions within the test file are execute/skipped/failed

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.jemtucker.domain.HelloWorldTest
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 s - in com.jemtucker.domain.HelloWorldTest
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone have any ideas why these aren't running?

Comment: did you set the testSourceDirectory as mentioned in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html ? it is the compiler plugin that compiles the tests, that config is then correct if you see errors. But running tests is done by the surefire plugin that needs some configuration as well (that property in the kotlin guide, see: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testSourceDirectory).

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a dependency - unfortunately this was not obvious at all and was only discovered after I re-wrote the `pom.xml` from scratch...

For anyone with the same issue, adding the `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency resolved this issue for me.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: well that makes sense as well :) you could accept your own answer, so one can see the question as resolved.